# How to download Highchart PDFs in Mobile Apps?

Tags: ionic-framework, highcharts, ionic3

I am using the Ionic version - 5.4.16 and am required to download PDF/Images files from HighCharts Options. On the browser, while development, it's working.
But in Ionic Build, it isn't.

[image]

I tried to inspect the changes and received this message on clicking "Download options.

> Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type image/png: "https://export.highcharts.com/"

Please advise.

Comment: [Exporting](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting) module is loading properly, do you have possibility to check?

Comment: On the browser, the download Exports is working. But in Ionic Build, I'm getting:
Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type image/png: "https://export.highcharts.com/"

Comment: In Ionic you build for Android or iOS yes?

Comment: Yes - currently for Android.

Comment: It looks like media type settings are changing, for pdf it should be Content-Type: application/pdf. I will check this and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem arises because the export module on Android works only for images.

Comment: Even Images are not downloading.

Comment: can you please look into this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72317542/in-highchart-mobile-view-bars-get-collected-at-one-side