# In Highchart mobile view, bars get collected at one side

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Can anyone advise why

- the bottom lines are collected at starting &
- graph-line appears on the rest of the view on mobile?
  Is it some configuration error or does it have some meaning?

[image]

[image]

Considering the first image, you can see the green line and its associated bottom bars. But those bars are not present beneath the blue graph.
And same with the second screenshot.

Comment: I need a more detailed description and a look at your code, could you improve your question?

Comment: I just added one more line at the bottom.

Comment: Chart config it's essential to say something about this case.